# Law of conservation of energy and kinetic energy: deformation of a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, spring

**Problem:**
*A block B of 1,5 kg is attached to the right of a spring (not deformed, with its right side attach to a wall) with a constant of $k = 80 N/m$ and, at rest, the block enter in collision with another identical block A. The block A moves to the left with a velocity of 5 m/s before the collision. Consider successively a restitution coefficient between the two blocks of $e = 1$ and $e = 0$. There is no friction in this problem.

a) the maximum deformation of the spring.

b) the final velocity of the block A.*

---

I have some difficulty to start this problem. I have an example with a block falling on a spring, but I have a hard time to apply it on a horizontal collision. I started by drawing a diagram of the two blocks before the collision. Block B is not moving and block A is going to the left. I also draw a diagram of the two blocks after the collision. The block B is going to the left and pushing the spring, and the block A is going to the right. (I'm going to use the french notation)

Since the restitution coefficient is 1 (impact perfectly elastic), the two blocks will go in an opposite direction with the same velocity they had before the impact. So block A will go right at 5 m/s and B will stay at 0 m/s but the spring will be compress.

Later, the block B will be push to the right with the elongation of the spring and then the two blocks will stick together and continue to the right with a restitution coefficient of 0 (impact perfectly plastic).

**So, I understand what is happening, but I need some help for the steps to follow to resolve this problem. Can someone help me understand?**

---

**Note:** if you have some problem understanding the problem, it is probably because I translated it from a french book. We do not use the same exact term in french (for example, the exact
translation from french of "velocity" is "speed"), so just ask for more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in the first situation(elastic impact), the block A will stand still after the impact and the block B will continue at 5m/s.

You have to make the summary of momentum(quantité de mouvement) and kinetic energy to solve those problems.

For the spring deflection, the maximum deflection will occur at speed 0, 0 kinetic energy, as all the energy will be store in the spring. You need to calculate the kinetic energy of the system then calculate how much deflection you need to achieve that amount of energy. The energy stored in a spring is define E=.5*k*x

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the treatment you need to consider. Body 1 velocity before and after impact, $v_1^I$ and $v_1^F$ and similarly for body 2, $v_2^I$ and $v_2^F$.

Effect of impulse $J$ on bodies

$$ -J = m_1 (v_1^F-v_1^I ) $$
 $$ J = m_2 (v_2^F-v_2^I ) $$

Definition of coefficient of restitution $\epsilon$

$$ v_2^F-v_1^F = -\epsilon ( v_2^I-v_1^I ) $$

From the above you get

$$ J = (\epsilon+1) \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2 } (v_2^I-v_1^I) $$

and

$$ v_1^F = v_1^I -  \frac{J}{m_1} $$

$$ v_2^F = v_2^I +  \frac{J}{m_2} $$

Then you can work out the spring and motion questions.